# HttpError: invalid json response body at https://github.com/... Unexpected token o in JSON at position

Tags: octokit

Hello i'm fetching data from github api as follow from `octokit`

```
 const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: "jhp_bOEN6EWOqtBcUBPIe0hlvEralCbNi0v2TE" //i've changed my github auth token) 
  });
```

and an onSubmit form as

```
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userData = await octokit.request(`GET /users/${inputValue}`, {
        username: `${inputValue}`
      });
      console.log(userData, "userData came");
      //setUser(userData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error getting data", err);
      setUser("Invalid user data");
    }
  };
```

but when user submit ,
I get this error all the time

```
HttpError: invalid json response body at https://api.github.com/users/something?username=something reason: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at eval (https://wu68u9.csb.app/node_modules/@octokit/request/dist-web/index.js:99:11)

    at async onSubmit (https://wu68u9.csb.app/src/Search.js:50:24)
```

Is there something wrong i'm doing here?

Comment: Same here! did you solve it?